# PHP regex - Как получить значение href?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<a href="https://pefilme.com/runaway-bride-de-buna-voie-si-nesilita-de-nimeni-1999/"><strong>Runaway Bride – De bună voie şi nesili...</strong></a>
```

Как я могу получить значение атрибута `href` или значение внутри кавычек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
$str = '<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>';
preg_match('/^<a.*?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*$/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Вывод:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>"
  [1]=>
  string(1) """
  [2]=>
  string(4) "that"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте.
js
`document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href`

Comment: но мне нужно на ПХП било

Comment: тогда всеровно нужно брать через js и отправлять запрос на сервер, в запросе передать интересующую вас инфу т.е. ссылку

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос

Посмотрите там все нормально расписано

Answer (score -2):

Узнать href:

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: но ето же jquery, мне нужно PHP

Comment: В смысле php? Как эти данные передаются в php? Где форма? Где ajax-запрос?

Comment: нее, у меня строка с html елементом